# Rails Api Save MiniMagick Image to Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I'm using MiniMagick to resize my image. My method looks something like that:

```
def resize
    mini_img = MiniMagick::Image.new(img.tempfile.path)
    mini_img.combine_options do |c|
      c.resize '50x50^'
      c.gravity 'center'
      c.extent '50x50'
    end

    mini_img
end
```

Resize works, but the problem is when I try save mini_img to Active Storage, because I get error `Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<MiniMagick::Image`. Can I somehow convert  MiniMagick::Image (mini_img) to normal image and save it into Active Storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Currently you are trying to save an instance of `MiniMagick::Image` to ActiveStorage, and that's why you receive that error. Instead you should attach the :io directly to ActiveStorage.

Using your example, if you wanted to attach `mini_img` to a hypothetical `User`, that's how you would do it:

```
User.first.attach io: StringIO.open(mini_img.to_blob), filename: "filename.extension"
```

In this example I am calling `to_blob` on `mini_img`, which is an instance of `MiniMagick::Image`, and passing it as argument to `StringIO#open`. Make sure to include the `:filename` option when attaching to ActiveStorage this way.

**EXTRA**

Since you already have the `content_type` when using `MiniMagick` you might want to provide it to ActiveStorage directly.

```
metadata = mini_img.data
User.first.attach io: StringIO.open(mini_img.to_blob), filename: metadata["baseName"], content_type: metadata["mimeType"], identify: false
```

Comment: Looks nice, but I have question - is there any way to save this `io: StringIO.open(mini_img.to_blob), filename: metadata["baseName"], mime_type: metadata["mimeType"], identify: false` to variable?

Comment: First option works, but when I try to use second (extra option) I get error `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :mime_type`

Comment: @N0ne my bad, its `:content_type` not `:mime_type`, I updated my answer.

Comment: @N0ne if you want to pass the arguments to `#attach` using a variable, you can. Just put the arguments in a hash: `args = { io: StringIO.open(mini_img.to_blob), filename: metadata["baseName"], content_type: metadata["mimeType"], identify: false }` and pass the variable directly: `User.first.attach(args)`.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who will have a similar problem. I just changed method to:

```
def resize
MiniMagick::Image.new(img.tempfile.path).combine_options do |c|
    c.resize '50x50^'
    c.gravity 'center'
    c.extent '50x50'
  end

  img
end
```

In this solution, MiniMagick only resized the photo and did nothing else with it, so I didn't have to convert it again.